# [Doctrine2]How to count the amount of "likes" in the "comment" of a "post"

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, social-networking

I'm struggling with my own social network where i'm trying to sort the comments of a post by the amount of likes on them.
So i made three tables : a Post with many Comments and a Comment with many Likes. Of course, there's a User table to handle all of this.

```
public function loadProfilePost($user, $first = 0, $limit = 0)
{
    $q =    $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('post, comment')
            ->from('EvoSocialBundle:Post', 'post')
            ->leftJoin('post.comments', 'comment')
            ->where('post.user = :user')
            ->setParameter(':user', $user)
            ->addOrderBy('post.created', 'DESC');

    $q->setFirstResult($first);
    if($limit > 0)
        $q->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: are you trying to sort the comments in-query? or later in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

To sort comments by its count of likes you can add one more join in your query builder with likes entity then set group by criteria like `group by post.id,comments.id`, i have added `addSelect()` with count function to count the likes for comment and setting the result of count `AS HIDDEN` so that they will not be returned with the result set and will affect only the query builder part

```
public function loadProfilePost($user, $first = 0, $limit = 0)
{
    $q =    $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p, c')
            ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT  c.id) AS HIDDEN total_likes')
            ->from('EvoSocialBundle:Post', 'p')
            ->leftJoin('p.comments', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('c.likes', 'l')
            ->where('p.user = :user')
            ->setParameter(':user', $user)
            ->groupBy('p.id')
            ->addGroupBy('c.id')
            ->orderBy('total_likes','DESC');

    $q->setFirstResult($first);
    if($limit > 0)
        $q->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Somehow this is not working. The comments are not sorted by the amount of likes in my feed. I have no idea why.
I'm not sure if i'm allowed to ask an other question related to this one, but is there a way to set a particular limit to the amount of comments loaded ? I want to load only 3 comments per post.